# Creating a form with checkboxes for each meal entered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a menu planner and and started with basic form. I want to be able to enter an entre. If set entre has free of certain diets. I want to click on a checkbox, to switch to true. So I can save the state and render to the screen.

I tried different approaches and googled a lot but can't find anything that really works for me. I can get the checkboxes to switch to true, but it doesn't save the value changes to undefined. Or I had it work once, but it checked all the other checkboxes in the side object. Not what i want.

```
const ServiceForm = () => {

const service = {
  entre:{
    value:"",
    veg:false,
    glut:false,
    dairy:false
  },
 side:{
    value:"",
    veg:false,
    glut:false,
    dairy:false
}
}

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, service)
  

console.log(state)
  return (
    <div>
      <form className="form">
        <div className="meal-container">
          <div className="entre-form">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="entre.value"
              onChange={(event) => {
                dispatch({ type: "ENTRE", payload: event.target.value });
              }}
              className="entree"
              placeholder="entree"
            />
            <div className="diets">
              <input
                onChange={() => {
                  dispatch({ type: "ENTRE", veg: !state.entre.veg });
                }}
                checked={state.entre.veg}
                type="checkbox"
              />
              <label>Veg</label>

              <input type="checkbox" />
              <label>Gluten</label>

              <input type="checkbox" />
              <label>Dairy</label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="entre-form">
            <input type="text" name="sideOne" placeholder="Side One" />
            <div className="diets">
              <input
                onChange={() => {
                  dispatch({ type: "VEG", payload: !state.vegetarian });
                }}
                checked={state.vegetarian}
                type="checkbox"
              />
              <label>Veg</label>

              <input type="checkbox" />
              <label>Gluten</label>

              <input type="checkbox" />
              <label>Dairy</label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="entre-form">
            <input name="entre.value" placeholder="Side Two" />
            <div className="diets">
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <label>Veg</label>

              <input type="checkbox" />
              <label>Gluten</label>

              <input type="checkbox" />
              <label>Dairy</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="entre-form">
            <textarea
              name="description"
              className="description"
              placeholder="description"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ServiceForm;
```

My reducer function

```
export const reducer = (state, action) =>{

switch(action.type){
    case 'ENTRE':return{
        ...state,
        entre:{
             value:action.payload,
            veg:action.veg
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reducer should be. I will also suggest you have separate actions for text input and checkbox.

```
switch(action.type){
    case 'ENTRE':return{
        ...state,
        entre:{
             ...entre,
             value:action.payload,
            veg:action.veg
        }
    }
   
}
}
```

Comment: I did try different approaches.  I had a case for each input.     ```["ENTRE", "SIDEONE", "SIDETWO", "VEG", "GLUT","DAIRY"]```       I encountered an issue, when I clicked on one veg, it clicked on all the other veg checkboxes as well. I couldn't figure how to attach the checkbox to the correct meal type.

Comment: You need any help with the separate actions??

Comment: I would say yes.

Comment: can you quickly create codesandbox for existing code..

Comment: Yes give me a moment

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-brattain-tbegh?file=/src/form.js

I left commented code in, so you can see other things I tried.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-water-qw6oi?file=/src/form.js. Here you go I have separated the Text and checkbox handling for Entre. You can take inspiration from here and code for other values..

Comment: Thanks A LOT for your time! I really appreciate it.

Comment: No worries..Cheers!! Now you can move ahead with your project or learning!!